# Swipe to the right then the left gives error ANDROID

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, apk, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating an application in Android in Eclipse with 3 screen with Swipe horizontally, the last tab got a Map Fragment, but when swipe right the first time is it normal when take a swipe to the left and back to make a right the application crashes and makes me this error, what could it be?

Thanks in advance

```
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): Process: com.sapires.JoesPizzariaGEN, PID: 10353
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.sapires.JoesPizzaria.Mapa.onCreateView(Mapa.java:16)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f070016, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5002)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    ... 25 more

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xozvj40uezkmg7/SwipeTab.rar

Answer (score 0):

Well, is seems to be caused by a problem in a xml file, but with the stack trace alone I'm afraid i can't help you.
However, check your layout file for that fragment, it may just be a duplicate id.